# Canonical correlation analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, canonical-correlation

I have data on variables such as age category, sex (3 categories), habits (each with a yes or no question), drug habits (each with a yes or no question), and osteoporosis index (oi) as continuous variables. I want to use canonical correlation analysis to find two sets of OI and age with other variables. Is it possible? How can I do it?interpret the results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Agree completely with the first comment. That said, as described your data is a mixture of metric scales -- binary, categorical, continuous. Like PCA, traditional CCA is not designed or intended for anything other than continuous metrics. Consider alternative methods in finite mixture models such as latent class models, supervised approaches to identifying latent structure. Statistical Innovations sells latent class software, has lots of white papers and tutorials on the topic.